# Is the pressure in an HPLC system the same throughout?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography, separation-techniques

I'm not sure if I'm articulating myself well enough, but here's my problem: I have a current HPLC system, where we typically have backpressure readouts of around 15 MPa. We are looking to get a new HPLC, and the rep said its DAD detector has a maximum pressure of 6 MPa. My questions are:

- Is the pressure at the pump outlet the same as the pressure at the column inlet and outlet?
- What pressure is actually being shown on the system readout when looking at the pump? (I'm assuming just the pressure at the pump outlet)
- Is the pressure at the detector usually significantly less than at the pump outlet?
- Assuming everything transfers from one system to our new one, and we end up with the same types of backpressures, will I have issues with this new detector?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. The pressure displayed is between pump and column inlet. There's a pressure gradient from the column inlet to the outlet, so the pressure reaching the detector is significantly less than the readout.